# Node MongoDB Multiple Api not working at Simultaneously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two API both Get type first one returns 25000 records and the second one return a single document.
When I hit the first API using the browser for 25000 records and at the same time I hit the second API on a new tab so the second API is waiting for the first to finish after that second is executed.
I want both API can run parallelly

Code

My first API -

```
exports.testApi = async(req,res) => {
    var data = await Task.find({}).limit(25000).exec();

    return res.status(200).send({success:true,message:'Record fetch Successfully',data:data}).end();
    
}
```

Second API

```
exports.testApi2 = async(req,res) => {
    var data = await Timesheet.findOne({}).exec();

    return res.status(200).send({success:true,message:'Record fetch Successfully',data:data}).end();
    
}
```

Comment: Ever heard why node isn’t a good solution for large projects well this is one example of that either way you can accomplish this by making node behave in multi process

Comment: What happens if you run both queries from separate Mongo shell instances? In other words: have you ruled out that the issue isn't being caused by MongoDB not having enough resources available to run the second query while the first one is still being processed? Have you tried using a [lean query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) for the 25K one?